# Close button c# windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to close the app by clicking one button but it's not working.

this is my code.

```
 private void buttonclose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

Comment: Don't use `Application.Exit`, because it's too destructive. Just close the window (call `Close()`). But your actual problem could be that you didn't register this event handler.

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Dialecticus said, it could be that you never registered the event handler. In your form designer, when you double click the button it will register the click event for you automatically. If you didn't do that and your code was just copy/pasted you would have to go into the events to "wire" them yourself.

If that's not your issue, you could try using `Environment.Exit()` or `this.Close()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code, it will diffidently work

```
private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
  this.Close();
}
```

Comment: What if the form is not the main form?

Comment: @Enigmativity bubble the form closing up to the main form, then call Close for main form

Comment: @GianPaolo - I know what to do, but the OP might not so this was a suggestion to improve the answer.

Comment: sorry @Enigmativity, I thought you were the OP, I didn't check the question